# Install Xcode 7 on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6, xcode7

I am running Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite and have Xcode 6.4 installed.

In order to run my Apache Cordova app on iPhone 6 with iOS 9 i need to have Xcode 7 and higher.

Is there a way to install and use Xcode 7 along with Xcode 6 on my Mac?
If yes please advise with the steps.

**Edit**

I was able to install Xcode 7.3 beta 2, but i can't open the app. When i go to /Applications folder and do open Xcode-beta.app i get this error LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10825 for the file /Applications/Xcode-beta.app.

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as that just rename the exciting xcode to some other name and then install the new version.If your are using xcode-command line tools use the xcode-select command in terminal to switch the command-line tools to the current version.`man xcode-select` in Terminal will give you the command doc.

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can use it. Just change download the dmg file of xcode 7 and install it. At installation time keep it both. No replace

Comment: The xcore 7 requires OSX 10.10.4 or later